# How to eliminate redundant if statement in set label text function?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have Python functions that is used to set labels based on input parameters. There is a parameter called `reset` which resets all labels. How can I get rid of redundant `if not reset`? There should be a smarter approach...

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention a pretty significant point. There are 3 ways of calling this function:

1. ft = 1 and reset = False, t != None, a != None
2. ft != 1 and reset = False, i != None
3. reset = 1

   def set_labels_text(fn, ft, t=None, a=None, i=None, reset=False):
       tt = ''
       at = ''
       it = ''

   ```
   if ft == 1
       if not reset:
           tt = 'bla bla 1 %s' % t
           at = 'bla bla 2 %s' % a
       get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label1').text = tt
       get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label2').text = at
   else:
       if not reset:
           it = 'bla bla 3 %s' % i
       get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label3').text = it
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about moving the `if not reset` block out of the other if else condition blocks

```
def set_labels_text(fn, ft, t=None, a=None, i=None, reset=False):
    tt = ''
    at = ''
    it = ''

    if not reset:
        tt = 'bla bla 1 %s' % t
        at = 'bla bla 2 %s' % a
        it = 'bla bla 3 %s' % i

    if ft == 1:
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label1').text = tt
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label2').text = at
    else:
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label3').text = it
```

Comment: You might also make this an `if reset: ... else: ...`, and/or condense the three lines above to `tt = at = it = ''`

Comment: I forgot to mention a pretty significant point. Could you please look at my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `tt` and `at` are only provided when `ft == 1`. `it` is only provided when `ft != 1` (else).

Comment: This function can basically handle 4 different operations:
1. `set_labels_text(fn='Hello', ft=1, t=100, a=200)`,
2. `set_labels_text(fn='Hello', ft=2, i=1000)`,
3. `set_labels_text(fn='Bla', ft=1, reset=True)`
4. `set_labels_text(fn='BlaBla', ft=2, reset=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go for this solution!

```
def set_labels_text(fn, ft, t=None, a=None, i=None, reset=False):
    at = None
    it = None
    tt = None
    if reset:
        it = 'bla bla 3 %s' % i
    else:
        at = 'bla bla 2 %s' % a
        tt = 'bla bla 1 %s' % t;

    if ft == 1
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label1').text = tt or ''
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label2').text = at or ''
    else:
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label3').text = it or ''
```

Comment: I forgot to mention a pretty significant point. Could you please look at my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `tt` and `at` are only provided when `ft == 1`. `it` is only provided when `ft != 1` (else).

Comment: I think in this case I would recommend to write different funtions for the different use cases. I also did some modification in the code. But I think in general it is not good practice to have so much if...else condition depending on the input parameters!

Comment: Your answer won't work because`at` and `tt` are not defined when `ft != 1`

Comment: do you see or ' ' ? In your example you also don not define at and tt if ft is not 1. I'm out!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using the ternary condition operator `x = y if condition else z`, although it requires checking the state of `reset` more than once:

```
def set_labels_text(fn, ft, t=None, a=None, i=None, reset=False):
    if ft == 1:
        tt = 'bla bla 1 %s' % t if not reset else ''
        at = 'bla bla 2 %s' % a if not reset else ''
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label1').text = tt
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label2').text = at
    else:
        it = 'bla bla 3 %s' % i if not reset else ''
        get_component('template' + ft).get_component(fn + 'Label3').text = it
```

Comment: I forgot to mention a pretty significant point. Could you please look at my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `tt` and `at` are only provided when `ft == 1`. `it` is only provided when `ft != 1` (else).

Comment: Do you need `tt` and `at` at all, if `ft==1` (respectively `it`, if `ft!=1`)? If not, you can just move the declarations into the if-statements.

Comment: This function can basically handle 4 different operations:
1. `set_labels_text(fn='Hello', ft=1, t=100, a=200)`,
2. `set_labels_text(fn='Hello', ft=2, i=1000)`,
3. `set_labels_text(fn='Bla', ft=1, reset=True)`
4. `set_labels_text(fn='BlaBla', ft=2, reset=True)`

Comment: The last two (3 and 4) are used to set label text to ''

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. I however agree with another comment in this thread to split your function into multiple functions, e.g. for setting and resetting the labels. This improves readability and interpretability of your code.

Comment: Would this be more efficient than my code?. You are 'iffing' 3 times

Comment: No, it's not more efficient, that's correct. However, I don't think that computational efficiency should be an issue here.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution to have 1 if instead of 2 or 3. Thank you for your help!